# Can you make one or more layout constraints conditional on another constraint being broken? (To deal with overlapping views)

Tags: cocoa, autolayout

I have a number of (dynamic) views arranged vertically.  For the sake of this example, let's say that they're aligned to the center of their superview, based on their distance from the top edge, like so:

[image: Original layout]

Now it may be the case that these two views overlap vertically:

[image: Overlapping layout]

When the views overlap, I would like to move them in the horizontal plane so they no longer overlap.

This can be achieved by checking if there is an overlap after each layout, and dynamically adding constraints if so, but I'd like to know if there's a way to do this which can be set up once and then will automatically occur when the views overlap.

---

For example, one way of doing this manually would be to add the constraints shown below:

[image: Desired layout]

In other words, I could add three additional constraints:

- one, in brown, fixing a minimum horizontal distance between the views
- two, in yellow, saying that the spacing between the views and the center X of their superview must be equal

(This particular solution won't scale nicely to more than two views, but I'm interested in the proof of concept here more than anything.)

---

Taking the simple two-view example above, is there any way to add the horizontal constraints I suggest (or, indeed, any other set of constraints) once, and have them take effect when the views overlap?

In other words, I would like to make them conditional, in some sense, on the vertical distance between the bottom edge of the top view and the top edge of the bottom view being negative.

---

tl;dr

**Can you make one layout constraint conditional on another constraint (either on the value of that constraint, or on that constraint being broken)?**